# How do I know I'm not using any XFCE programs? 

Tags: xfce

What is XFCE?

How do I know what programs are using it? 
because another answer told me to remove xfce files, and I want to know if I'm using them.

I was told to remove a [bunch of XFCE related programs](http://paste.ubuntu.com/729983/) to fix an [issue with google-chrome](https://askubuntu.com/q/76040/10698), how can I know that I'm not using those programs?

Comment: This seems to be really vague. Can you explain a little more in-depth what you're looking for? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XFCE is a desktop environment similar to GNOME, Unity, and KDE (in idea, not execution/presentation).  It is considered more lightweight than the others I listed, and also keeps to a more "traditional" desktop layout.

As to the applications that "use" it, I'm not sure how to answer that.  There are of course an interconnected set of tools/applications that make up the base XFCE install, but no application uses it anymore that it would use any other desktop environment.

---

> I was told to remove a bunch of XFCE related programs to fix an issue
>   with google-chrome, how can I know that I'm not using those programs?

Then this will remove XFCE, thereby effecting you if you are using XFCE.  Otherwise, whatever desktop environment you're using is providing equivalent functions through other packages.  I don't see why you would need to remove XFCE for Chrome, though, I use XFCE with Chrome (Chromium) just fine.

Answer (score 1):

XFCE is a lightweight Desktop environment based on GTK+.  It is a peer of GNOME/KDE/Unity and runs the same apps.  Most apps in XFCE are GTK+.

Answer (score 0):

in Synaptic manager type xfce and you should see a lot of xfce-oriented stuff, some might be installed

Comment: I want to know if they are **running** if they aren't installed, how would they be running?

Comment: YOU SAID: "another answer told me to remove xfce files", "I was told to remove a bunch of XFCE related programs to fix an issue with google-chrome, how can I know that I'm not using those programs?" - if you uninstall them, you would know that you are not using them. If you want to keep them,and see if they run or not, maybe your question should be adjusted.

Comment: I wanted to know if I was using them before I removed them, so nothing would break. I want to know if the xfce programs are running before, so I know that nothing will happen if I remove them.

Comment: I understand now what you want, but THAT is not clear in your question. Please edit your question according to your last comment. - You should also specify what is your desktop environment. Not as an answer, but just as an opinion, it seems to me too much fuss removing all xfce related software just to fix a google-chrome issue. I would start by reinstalling it, trying a custom download manager like axel,  replacing google chrome with chromium, and even giving it all up for firefox. And after some time trying it again ... BEFORE doing all that.